# Alamofire 4 error request 'extra argument in call'

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have updated to Xcode8, swift3 and Alamofire 4 and am now getting an error 'extra argument 'method' in call' on the below line beginning 'Alamofire.request'

```
var pulseVoteEndpoint: String = "https://example.com/app1/votingapi/set_votes.json"

var pulseNewVote = ["votes":[["value":valueString,"uid":uidString,"entity_id":nidInt,"entity_type":"node","tag":"points","value_type":"points"]]]

Alamofire.request(pulseVoteEndpoint, method: .post, parameters: pulseNewVote, encoding: .json)
         .response { request, response, data, error in
             debugPrint(response)
             print(request)
             print (response)
             print (error)
         }
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Which extra argument does it say?

Comment: Oh, you might need to specify the type of `pulseNewVote` ... `var pulseNewVote: [String: Any] = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The `encoding` argument of `request(...)` expects `static` properties, not `enum` cases.

We can take a look at the signature of the static `request(...)` method of `Alamofire` ([Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Alamofire.swift#L132))

> ```
> public func request(
>     _ url: URLConvertible,
>     method: HTTPMethod = .get,
>     parameters: Parameters? = nil,
>     encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
>     headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil)
>     -> DataRequest
> { /* ... */ }
> ```

The first argument is one which conforms to the protocol `URLConvertible`, to which [`String` is valid](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Alamofire.swift#L38); all good so far.

The type of the 2nd argument is [simply an `enum`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/ParameterEncoding.swift#L30) to which `.post` is a valid case, OK.

The third argument should be of type `Parameters`, which is [a typealias for `[String: Any]`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/ParameterEncoding.swift#L45)

> ```
> /// A dictionary of parameters to apply to a `URLRequest`.
> public typealias Parameters = [String: Any]
> ```

The argument you supply, `pulseNewVote`, is of type `Dictionary<String, Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>>`, but should still be able to be consumed by the expected argument type (`Dictionary<String, Any>`). So this should still be OK, even if you might want to consider helping Swift out by explicitly type annotating the type of `pulseNewVote` to `[String: Any]`:

```
var pulseNewVote: [String: Any] = ...
```

The fourth argument, the encoding, however, is not an `enum`, but a [protocol `ParameterEncoding`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/ParameterEncoding.swift#L48) to which a few `struct` types conform. These type have static members (returning an instance of `self`) which may look like `enum` cases when explicitly type, but which must include the explicit typing

> ```
> public struct JSONEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
>
>     // MARK: Properties
>     /// Returns a `JSONEncoding` instance with default writing options.
>     public static var `default`: JSONEncoding { return JSONEncoding() }
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Hence, you need to replace the value supplied to your fourth argument, `.json`, with e.g. `JSONEncoding.default`. With this fix, your call to `request` should look like:

```
Alamofire.request(pulseVoteEndpoint, method: .post, parameters: pulseNewVote, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
```

The error you're given (additional parameters) come from, however, the completion handler to the `reponse` call. The completion handler supplied to a call to `response` is one which takes a single [`DefaultDataResponse`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Response.swift#L28) as argument (not 4 different arguments as in your attempt). An instance of the `DefaultDataResponse` type have public members `request`, `response`, `data` and `error`, which you may access via the single `response` parameter (of type `DefaultDataResponse`) in the completion handler. Adapting the completion handler in your `response` call to this fact (using the [example from the Alamofire documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), we may construct the final `request` and `response` chained call:

```
Alamofire.request(pulseVoteEndpoint, method: .post, parameters: pulseNewVote, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    .response { response in
    // note that these are all optionals, so
    // you might want to unwrap them first
    print(response.request)
    print(response.response)
    print(response.error)
}
```

Comment: PS in another usage of this in my code, after the 'response in' line I have 'let value = response.result.value else {'  But this is now not working in Xcode8. Could I ask how to handle that response?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.json` for encoding, try `JSONEncoding.default`.

Your paramters should be casted to: `[String : Any]?`

This is an issue with compiler which falsely report error for extra argument.

In the end, your line should look like this:

```
Alamofire.request(pulseVoteEndpoint, method: .post, parameters: pulseNewVote as [String : Any]?, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
         .response { request, response, data, error in
// rest of the code
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion. I've tried it and am getting an error on 'response' that says "cannot call value of non-function type HTTPURLResponse'. Would love your thoughts!

Comment: For that part, please see @dfri answer so we don't get duplicate here - it is now only one variable : response which contains request, response and error

Answer (score 0):

I had an Xcode bug causing this error to occur because part of the url string was being force unwrapped when it didn't need to be.

Here is the call with the incorrectly unwrapped property:

```
Alamofire.request(baseUrl + "notes/\(note.id!)", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { [weak self] response in
```

Here is the fixed call that will eliminate the error:

```
Alamofire.request(baseUrl + "notes/\(note.id)", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { [weak self] response in
```

Comment: because it is easier to copy/paste locally and try to replicate the issue (instead of typing it all into my xcode)

Comment: Okay, updated with code to assist others in replicating. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> In my case The problem was in the headers argument. It should be
>   [String:String]

Plus the parameters argument should be [String:Any]

I used **Alamofire 4.8.2** as the below to resolve this compilation error:

```
let parameters = ["key":"value","key2":1] as [String:Any]
let headers = ["header_1":"value"] as [String:String]
let encoding:URLEncoding = URLEncoding.default

Alamofire.request("base_url",
                   method: .post,
                   parameters: parameters,
                   encoding: encoding,
                   headers: headers)
```